# How to get the data from Libre Office Calc and use it in a bash script?

Tags: bash, scripts, libreoffice

I am Using Ubuntu 20.04.1

I have Libre Office Calc. with two columns working.
I do edit these two columns weekly once..

```
A   987654320
B   987654321
C   987654322
D   987654323
E   987654324
F   987654325
G   987654326
```

I need to write a bash script that gets the data from the above two columns and make a text file like below as an example..

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
FN:$(content of column1, row1)
N:$(content of column1,row1)
TEL;TYPE=cell:$(content of column2, row1)
END:VCARD

BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
FN:$(content of column1, row2)
N:$(content of column1,row2)
TEL;TYPE=cell:$(content of column2, row2)
END:VCARD

and so on till it finds the content at last existing row
```

Comment: You can copy and paste the data from Calc to a text file and then use that as input for your bash script.  However, a more direct method would be to use a LibreOffice Basic macro, from within Calc, to read the data from the original worksheet, write it to a second worksheet in the format you describe, and then save this second worksheet as a text file.

Comment: thank you for your response.. so basically is that not possible to read the data from Calc via bash script?

Comment: Don't know if this helps but you can have LibreOffice Calc call bash scripts and pass cell contents as parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can get the needed result with two-step process:

1. we convert spreadsheet to *file.txt* (really CSV):

   ```
   localc --headless --convert-to txt:"Text - txt - csv (StarCalc)" file.ods
   ```
2. use some AWK scripting:

   ```
   awk -F, '{
   print "BEGIN:VCARD"
   print "VERSION:3.0"
   print "FN:"$1
   print "N:"$1
   print "TEL;TYPE=cell:"$2
   print "END:VCARD"
   print ""
   }' file.txt
   ```

Comment: +1; @UnKNOWn, If you wish to understand what happens under the hood, you can unzip the `ods` file and extract the data manually (with linux command lines) from the file `content.xml`, but this extraction task is much easier with the command line `localc ... --convert-to txt  ...`